# Crudbooster laravel - How to make different column relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, crudbooster

I have two table 1. table_a 2. table_b
And all table have company_id. I want to make relationship among this two table using same company id . Like

```
select * from table_a left join table_b on table_a.company_id = table_b.company_id;
```

Please help me out if its really possible. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$data = DB::table('table_a')->leftJoin('table_b', 'table_a.company_id', '=', 'table_b.company_id')->get();
```

Or raw:

```
$users = DB::table('table_a')
                     ->select(DB::raw('query here'))
                     ->get();
```

More on:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries

Comment: Thank you @Antonio . I want it for Laravel Crudbooster package .